# Scikit-learn - Cross validates score and predictions at one go?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something really easy but I have a hard time trying to google something out.

I can see there are `cross_val_score` and `cross_val_predict` functions in scikit-learn. However, I can't find a way to get both score and predictions at one go. Seems quite obvious as calling the functions above one after another is a waste of computing time. Is there a `cross_val_score_predict` function or similar?

Comment: This might help http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation

Comment: Thanks, although I wanted to take a look at the metrics variability (as answered on the below's question)

Comment: This does seem such a natural thing to do it surprises me it is not implemented. Typically, I want to get an oof score and an oof prediction so I can rate a model and then keep the off prediction to ensemble later.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `cross_val_predict` then you can check the metric on the result. It is not a waste of compute time because `cross_val_predict` doesn't compute scores itself.

This won't give you per-fold scores though, only the aggregated score (which is not necessarily bad). I think you can workaround that by creating KFold / ... instance explicitly and then using it to split the `cross_val_predict` result.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the obvious approach. The thing is I actually wanted to take a look at the metrics variability, which is not possible this way. I'll write the code myself then, as you suggested, just did not want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks